# IRW does not show any thing

Tags: raspbian, python, remote, input-device, lirc

I want to use an infrared remote control.

I'm using an infrared diode tsop38238. first I disabled the device tree because mode2 did not work at the beginning.

After disabling I recorded my remote very well and now I have a lircd.conf but when I try to run "IRW" and press any buttons on remote it shows anything.

But my receiver and remote are work I know.

Where is the problem? Any idea?